# Arel: order by association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
class Question
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I want to find all questions ordered by the number of votes they have. I want to express this in Arel (in Rails 3) without using any counter caches.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Question.select("questions.*, a.vote_count AS vote_count").
 joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT b.question_id, COUNT(b.id) AS vote_count
    FROM   votes b
    GROUP BY b.question_id
  ) a ON a.question_id = questions.id")
```

Solution is DB agnostic. Make sure you add an index on the `question_id` column in the `votes` table( you should add the index even if you don't use this solution).

Answer (score 5):

Try next one:

```
Question.joins(:votes).select("questions.id, *other question coulmns*, count(votes.id) as vote_count").order("vote_count DESC").group("questions.id")
```

Comment: did you mean `group("questions.id")`?

Comment: Is there an easy way to get ```*other question columns*``` in the select. I guess it will be needed in ```group()``` too.

Comment: @Akshay Rawat maybe try "questions.*"

Comment: Just as a counterpoint, this sort of complex query is where SQL shines and you might want to look into using raw SQL for this one.